# Obtain full system path from std::ofstream variable when relative path is given c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I am writing a txt file to a relative directory path, here is the code snippet

```
std::ofstream file1("./../../newfile.txt");
file1 << "Something written to file" << endl;
file1.close();
```

The given relative path is `./../../newfile.txt`.

**Question** - Can I obtain the full path of the file in my computer from the `file1` variable. I want to print the final full path where the file was written in the code.

I did put a break point and check the fields, but it does not show the full system path.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/absolute

Comment: There is no way to get a path (relative or absolute) from an `ofstream` variable (at least according to C++ standard).

Comment: @john The above solution works `absolute(std::filesystem p)`, just that I need to use `std::filesystem` to give the file path instaed of normal `std::string`

Comment: @Nitron_707 Yes it does, but it's getting the absolute path from the relative path, not from the `file1` variable, which is what you asked about.

Comment: @john, yes you are correct, from `file1` you cannot, so I adapted the code to use `std::filesystem`

Comment: @Nitron_707 OK, glad you got the problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, `fstream`s only **use** the path, they don't store it.

Although you can get around that shortcoming by simply storing the path in a variable.

```
auto path = "./../../newfile.txt";
std::ostream file1{path};

auto fullPath = std::filesystem::absolute(std::filesystem::path(path));

std::cout << fullPath.c_str();
```